# Vue-router - using two different paths, children don't load from second path

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

children in route, name: matchDayRegistrationResult don't get loaded, when I move them to name: matchDays they load fine. But I need a different top level component, HomepageLayoutRatio5050 -> HomepageLayoutRatio2575

I could not find a working example in the Vue docs

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes:
    [
        {
            path: '/:lang',
            name: 'matchDays',
            component: HomepageLayoutRatio5050,
            children: [
            {
                path: '/:lang',
                components: {
                    descriptionBlock: MatchDaysDescription,
                    mainBlock: MatchDaysTable,
                    notesBlock: MatchDaysNotes
                }
            },{
                path: '/:lang/matchday/registration/:id',
                name: 'matchDayRegistration',
                components: {
                    descriptionBlock: RegistrationFormDescription,
                    mainBlock: RegistrationForm
                }
            }]
        },
        {
            path: '/:lang/matchday/registration/result/:id',
            name: 'matchDayRegistrationResult',
            component: HomepageLayoutRatio2575,
            children: [
                {
                    path: '/:lang/matchday/registration/result/:id',
                    components: {
                        descriptionBlock: RegistrationResultDescription,
                        mainBlock: RegistrationResultDetails,
                        notesBlock: RegistrationResultNotes
                    }
                }]
        }
    ]
});
```

HomepageLayoutRatio2575 does load,

> but children:  descriptionBlock: RegistrationResultDescription 
>   mainBlock: RegistrationResultDetails  notesBlock:
>   RegistrationResultNotes Don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found THE solution, as the localisation part, /:lang was the culprit, blocking the second route (...logic) I reordered the routing schema.

To the benefit of people, having hard times, looking for complex vue router-view solutions, localisation aware, here's the solution :-)

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes:
        [
            {
                path: '/:lang',
                component: HomeSweetHome,
                children: [{
                    path: '/:lang',
                    name: 'matchDays',
                    components: {
                        homepageSidebarLayoutRatio: HomepageSidebarLayoutRatio5050,
                        homepageMainLayoutRatio: HomepageMainLayoutRatio5050,
                        footer: FooterGray
                    },
                    children: [
                        {
                            path: '/:lang',
                            components: {
                                descriptionBlock: MatchDaysDescription,
                                mainBlock: MatchDaysTable,
                                notesBlock: MatchDaysNotes
                            }
                        },{
                            path: '/:lang/matchday/registration/:id',
                            name: 'matchDayRegistration',
                            components: {
                                descriptionBlock: RegistrationFormDescription,
                                mainBlock: RegistrationForm
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },{
                    path: '/:lang/matchday/registration/result/:id',
                    components: {
                        homepageSidebarLayoutRatio: HomepageSidebarLayoutRatio2575,
                        homepageMainLayoutRatio: HomepageMainLayoutRatio2575,
                        footerNotesBlock: RegistrationResultFooterNotes,
                        footer: FooterBlack,
                    },
                    children:[{
                        path: '/:lang/matchday/registration/result/:id',
                        name: 'matchDayRegistrationResult',
                        components: {
                            descriptionBlock: RegistrationResultDescription,
                            mainBlock: RegistrationResultDetails
                        }
                    }]
                }]
            }
        ]
});
```